# How to set iOS UITextField placeholder color? (RubyMotion + iOS)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, rubymotion

How to use RubyMotion to set a textField's placeholder text foreground color?

Example code:

```
textField = UITextField.alloc.init
textField.placeholder = "Hello World"
```

The placeholder text shows up gray; I want it to be red.

This is using RubyMotion, not Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Use an attributed string like this:

```
self.attributedPlaceholder = 
  NSAttributedString.alloc.initWithString(
    self.placeholder || "Hello World",  
    attributes: {NSForegroundColorAttributeName => UIColor.redColor}
  )
```

This works on iOS7, and likely on iOS6, and not on earlier iOS versions.

Careful: be certain to use the hash syntax `key => val` instead of `key: val`.

Comment: voted correct... even though you're the originator of the question :)